# Execute some codes when closing an Asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, ashx

I want to delete a row in a Database table when a user closes an .aspx page. How could I do it? I know how to delete a row in a Database table but I don't know how to do it when a user leaves an .aspx page?

Comment: It's not trivial issue. Most close solution, to use web sockets, and do what you need on client disconnect. But I think it's much better find different work flow.

Comment: close or exit mean session end or just navigate to another page?

Comment: If you mean to handle the browser close, then you can handle this with the technique mentioned [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1116238.aspx?End+Session+When+Browser+Closed)

Comment: the session end. (when The user leave the current page or when the current page is not showing on the Browser)

Comment: Refer to the ASP.NET page lifecycle to help find the right event to override. It really depends what you want to do. There is an unload event.

Comment: I know, But the unload event triggers when we enter a page.

Comment: The Unload event is raised after the page has been fully rendered, sent to the client, and is ready to be discarded. At this point, page properties such as Response and Request are unloaded and cleanup is performed.

Comment: Don't forget the case if the browser crash, it won't send anything to the server. You will have no choice but to add a timestamp to the data and delete old rows. What is the information contained in that row?

Comment: @user3724490 The session doesn't end when the user leaves a page or they switch to another tab. You need to rethink your whole design if you need to rely on that, because it doesn't work conceptually. There's not a reliable way of handling what you want, though you can get close with web sockets or other async techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an ajax call to the "beforeunload" page html event. Just make sure to call ajax with async false, otherwise the page will be close before the code to delete the row actually runs. I'm assuming you are using jQuery for the ajax call.

For example, in html:

```
<body onbeforeunload="runCode();">

YOUR HTML....

<script type="text/javascript">
function runCode() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'YourCode.ashx',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //Do other things before navigating to other page or closing the browser
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
```

The file named YourCode.ashx will contain the code to delete your db row, or whatever else you want to be done. In this way the code will be run even if the user closes the browser. Just note that the async false call can lock your page if the code in YourCode.ashx has problems.

Comment: what should I paste after  //Do other things before navigating... ?

Comment: I know how to add.ashx file but I don't know how to use it. may you help me please?Thanks

Comment: after the //Do other... you can add whatever you want in javascript, it's not mandatory (for example you ashx may return a message saying whether the deletion was successful or not and you can show it to the user with an alert). The ashx is simply a code that runs without being part of a page, similar to a php file. You can find extensive example around (btw, the default ashx generated by Visual Studio is quite simple to understand itself)

Comment: Ok.For example I put this code in .ashx file but it did not show the message when I close the page( what is wrong?) `<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="YourCode" %> Imports System Imports System.Web Public Class YourCode : Implements IHttpHandler Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest MsgBox("Hello World") End Sub Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable Get Return False End Get End Property End Class`

Comment: there is an error it says: Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: @user3724490 Gabriele wrote "I'm assuming you are using jQuery for the ajax call." The `$` will be resolved if you use jQuery.