# How to use .ashx file to execute some codes when a user closes a webpage

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net, ashx

I want to execute some vb.net codes when a user closes a webpage. What should I do. I have this But I don't know how to use it.I have seen the bellow instrucions somewhere but I can not use it:

You can bind an ajax call to the "beforeunload" page html event. Just make sure to call ajax with async false, otherwise the page will be close before the code to delete the row actually runs. I'm assuming you are using jQuery for the ajax call.

For example, in html:

```
<body onbeforeunload="runCode();">
```

YOUR HTML....

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function runCode() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'YourCode.ashx',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //Do other things before navigating to other page or closing the browser
        }
    }); } 
</script>
 </body>
```

The file named YourCode.ashx will contain the code to delete your db row, or whatever else you want to be done. In this way the code will be run even if the user closes the browser. Just note that the async false call can lock your page if the code in YourCode.ashx has problems.

Comment: So where you facing problem?

Comment: I am not familiar with .ashx fine. For example How could I use this method to show a message just before closing the page? I want to implement this code on .ashx file: `MsgBox("hi")` you can also see this page: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739233/execute-some-codes-when-closing-an-asp-net-page]

Comment: there is an error it says: Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **jQuery**, you can use [unload event](http://api.jquery.com/unload/). Make sure to include jQuery.

***FYI:*** If you use jQuery unload event, remove `onbeforeunload="runCode();"` from body tag

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        This is content.

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).unload(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'YourCode.ashx',
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        // Do other things before navigating 
                        // to other page or closing the browser
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't use jquery so what should I use?

Comment: @user3724490 $.ajax is [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You are using **jQuery** *(althought you did not know that)*, but you did not include **jQuery Script**. It's why you are getting `Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined` error.